# Iframe for youtube video loads and then disappears on android chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, iframe, youtube, zurb-foundation

I am adding an iframe to display a video from youtube, the video appears fine and responsive across all devices except on android mobile chrome browser.The video appears for a second then disappears. On inspecting the element in chrome developer tools I can actually see that the Div that contains my iframe becomes empty after a second.

I have tried putting it in the flex video container provided by foundation (the site is using zurb foundation for responsive design) but still the issue persists, in fact no iframe video container is staying for more than a second. Any help is highly appreciated.

I have red these questions, but none of them solve my issue
[AngularJS: Embedding Youtube videos in iframe does not work on Android Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681146/angularjs-embedding-youtube-videos-in-iframe-does-not-work-on-android-chrome)

[youtube video quickly disappears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26529671/youtube-video-quickly-disappears)

[Why is my iframe video disappearing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685992/why-is-my-iframe-video-disappearing)

I dont have rights yet to post an image so i am sharing the snapshot here.
http://i61.tinypic.com/vfwjnk.png

The fullscreen-video-container in the class of the div which holds the iframe. You can see the div becomes empty after a second.

The console has no errors

Answer (score 1):

This was the first post I found on the topic. Ran into this just the other day. I *had* the embed URL variant so I was confused. This is all very simple. Realized it was a WordPress plugin trying to do tricky things with regex and handling it's own embed trickery. Disabling the related plugin made things work.